# Why is it not possible to add an integer to a "dereferenced" pointer variable in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, types

Coming from Python, I'm currently learning Go and trying to wrap my head around pointers.

I've written this code in order to understand the concept:

```
a := 1
b := &a
fmt.Println(b) // Shows the memory address of a
fmt.Println(*b) // Shows the value 1
*b++
fmt.Println(a) // Shows the value 2 (as expected)
```

I tried to play around with this code to improve my understanding. The following, however, does not work:

```
a := 1
b := &a
fmt.Println(b) // Shows the memory address of a
fmt.Println(*b) // Shows the value 1
b = *b + 1 // Compile error: invalid operation: b * +1 (mismatched types *int and int)
fmt.Println(a)
```

Apparently, `*b` is of type `*int`, while the value `1` is (obviously) of type `int`. However, why is it possible to increment the value of a with `*b++`in the first example?

Comment: `*b++` stands for `*b = *b + 1`, not `b = *b + 1`.

Comment: `b` is of type `*int`. `*b` is of type `int`. `*b + 1` is fine (and produces an `int`). The problem is the assignment to `b`, which is an `*int`, not an `int`. You'd get the same error by writing `b = *b` or `b = 1`.

Comment: What Go version are you using? I don't get that error you posted; I get "cannot use *b + 1 (type int) as type *int in assignment" ; which is much clearer and would have probably avoided your confusion in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the beginning:

`b := &a`

Here, `b` is of type `*int`, a pointer to a location in memory where value of `a` is stored. When you do `*b`, you are accessing a value from the location `b` pointer points to.

When you do `*b++`, it stands for `*b = *b + 1` and you are incrementing a value on the location `b` pointer points to.

`b = *b + 1` is invalid because you are trying to add `*b` and `1`, which are both type of `int`, to `b`, which is a pointer (type of `*int`).

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it not possible to add an integer to a “dereferenced” pointer variable in Go?

`b` is a pointer and dereferenced `b` is written as `*b`. `b = *b + 1` is invalid because you're trying to convert an integer to a pointer, which is not possible even when explicitly typecasted. You'll need to instead modify the data that pointer is pointing to, not the pointer itself: `*b = *b + 1`.

Take a look at the Go spec here regarding why `*b++` works: https://golang.org/ref/spec

> Operator precedence
>
> Unary operators have the highest precedence. As the ++ and -- operators form statements, not expressions, they fall outside the operator hierarchy. As a consequence, statement *p++ is the same as (*p)++.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an integer to a dereferenced (integer) pointer variable is possible and is working in your case correctly. However, assigning this value to a pointer variable is not acceptable in Go for type safety reasons. And it is normally not needed (but there is a way to reference any given address though). Hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a `*int` to an `int`. Hence, the error.
As b is a pointer to an integer, to do anything with that integer(read or write), you need to de-reference it. Below code will work as expected. That's what `*b++` does internally.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 1
    b := &a
    fmt.Println(b)  // Shows the memory address of a
    fmt.Println(*b) // Shows the value 1
    *b = *b + 1     // No Compile error
    fmt.Println(a)  // Shows the value 2
}
```

Try it here:
https://play.golang.org/p/2RX1CWD-AQC